# What cause my drupal 7 page put all the CSS inline in the source

Tags: drupal-7

I have a strange issue, why all my drupal 7 pages do not put the CSS in their link stylesheet, like the expected:

**LOCAL:**

```
<style type="text/css" media="all">@import url("http://some.dev/sites/all/themes/sometheme/css/normalize.css?lzrdw3");</style>
```

... etc

At **SOME STAGING** it prints the content of CSS inside the page source:

```
<style type="text/css" media="all">article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,nav,section{display:block}audio,canvas,video{display:inline-block;*display:inline;*zoom:1}audio:not([controls]){display:none}[hidden]{display:none} ......
```

This is fine at local, and they are both not aggregated either.

Any idea what might cause it so that I can articulate better to our sysadmin on what went wrong.

Thanks

UPDATE: Just realized, even drupal.org has this "issue". So is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marking this as won't fix, varnish or something. D.O has it